# Dynamic XML tags and JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How can I use JAXB to serialize and deserialize the following XML, considering that tags `complement1`, `2` and `3` are not required and XML might have `complement4`, `5`, `n`?

I thought about using `@XmlAnyElement` annotation, but I need to know that the value "First" belongs to the first complement, "Second" to the second, etc.

```
<resource>
    <id>Identifier</id>
    <name>Name</name>
    <complement1>First</complement1>
    <complement2>Second</complement2>
    <complement3>Third</complement3>
</resource>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can use @XmlAnyElement, and you do have access to the element name.
You need to use a "List of any" construct.
When JAXB unmarshalls the XML you will have a list of DOM Element objects, each of which contains the element name and contents.
I think you'd have to manually enforce that each element tag name matched the "complementN" pattern.

e.g. this is modified from one of the Oracle samples:

Schema:

```
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:sequence>
          <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Snippet from xjc generated Person class:

```
...
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String firstname;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String lastname;
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;
...
```

Test XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<person>
  <firstname>David</firstname>
  <lastname>Francis</lastname>
  <anyItem1>anyItem1Value</anyItem1>
  <anyItem2>anyItem2Value</anyItem2>
</person>
```

Test class:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "generated" );
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Person contents = (Person) u.unmarshal(Testit.class.getResource("./anysample_test1.xml"));
System.out.println("contents: " + contents);
System.out.println("  firstname: " + contents.getFirstname());
System.out.println("  lastname: " + contents.getLastname());
System.out.println("  any: ");
for (Object anyItem : contents.getAny()) {
    System.out.println("    any item: " + anyItem);
    Element ele = (Element) anyItem;
    System.out.println("      ele name: " + ele.getTagName());
    System.out.println("      ele text content: " + ele.getTextContent());
}
```

Output:

```
contents: generated.Person@1bfc93a
  firstname: David
  lastname: Francis
  any: 
    any item: [anyItem1: null]
      ele name: anyItem1
      ele text content: anyItem1Value
    any item: [anyItem2: null]
      ele name: anyItem2
      ele text content: anyItem2Value
```

Comment: Thanks, David. But this way I would have to add Element objects to List any. For reusability purposes, I think it would be better if I could create a class ComplementarField, for example, with attributes ordinal (int) and value (String). There is a way to deserialize complementN to a ComplementarField instance and add it to the list any?

Comment: No I don't think you can do that. This integer suffix isn't something you see in XML that much in my experience. Can you change the schema? Eg make the tag name always equal 'complement' and put the integer suffix in an attribute instead?

Comment: Yes, I understand. That's not the better way to represent that kind of values. Unfortunately, that XML is returned by a REST web service published by another company. I can't modify the schema, but I will suggest it to them. Today, my implementation iterates over all the document tree and handles the values manually. Thanks for your help! :)